# Why aren't my pictures appearing in the "pictures" section of the change wallpapers window?

Tags: gnome, system-settings, desktop-background

This is my Pictures folder. 
[image]
The folders inside all contain photos. When I look at the settings app to change wallpapers, I get this.
[image]

Why don't my photos appear in the "pictures" section?

Comment: Place them directory in the `Pictures` folder

Comment: If you are telling me to place one photo in the pictures file, I could do that, but I want all of my photos to appear in the settings app.

Comment: On going discussion, please be productive there: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712245

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNOME's background customisation option is very limited. Along with system background images and solid colours, it allows the user to choose images only from *Pictures*, **not even** from any subfolder of Pictures. You may do one on the following:

1. Place the image you want to set as background in Pictures folder, not inside any subfolder.
2. **Recommended option:** Use *GNOME Tweak Tool* to set images from wherever you like as your background image. Open the application and select your preferred image in **Background Location** option under **Desktop**.
   [image]
3. **Advanced option:** Use *dconf Editor* to set any image as background. Open the application and navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri`, disable *Use default value*, and set the path to your image in the *Custom value* field.