# Custom small sized wallpapers in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-shell, desktop-background

When setting a wallpaper in Ubuntu 17.04 I could choose from *tile*, *zoom*, *center*, *scale*, *fill* or *span* options.

Where can I found option for 'center' wallpaper behaviour in Ubuntu 17.10?

---

**Background**: I use two monitors with different resolutions. So I was more than happy to use small image as a wallpaper with white colour filling the rest of the screen.

This was done through *All Settings -> Appearance -> Look* tab in Unity, where I could select option "center" and white colour to fill the rest.

After updating to Ubuntu 17.10 I was not able to select my custom wallpaper from *Background -> Wallpaper* menu, so I went to the directory with the image and tried to "Set as Wallpaper" option in the menu, but it zoomed image to every screen resolution (it looks awful).

So I wonder - How can I set wallpaper to be centred without zoom and to use plain white colour for all the space left?

Comment: Related to: [Why aren't my pictures appearing in the “pictures” section of the change wallpapers window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960601/why-arent-my-pictures-appearing-in-the-pictures-section-of-the-change-wallpap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try using *(GNOME) Tweaks*. You may install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Launch Tweaks and go to *Desktop* section and select "*Centered*" in *Adjustment* under *Background*:

[image]

To fill the rest of your background with while colour, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#FFFFFF'
```

(Or follow the advanced option of my answer here: 
[Change background color to pitch black](https://askubuntu.com/a/943251/480481) , for white you'll have to use `#FFFFFF` instead of `#000000`).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was able to centered image as suggested! How can I change background colour to be white?

Comment: Thank you. I've installed `dconf-editor` and set *primary-color* to `#FFFFFF` for `/org/gnome/desktop/background/`. It did the trick!

Comment: @StanislavBondarenko Also added a command-line way to change the background colour easily so that one doesn't have to use *dconf Editor*.